# Recursive function for finding number of equivalence classes

Tags: equivalence-relations, recursive-algorithms

I have $n$ elements that can be ordered using $>, <, =$. The question is how to best calculate (in computer terms) the number of possible such orderings. For example, for $n=2$ the possible orders are:

- $a<b$
- $a=b$
- $b<a$

So $f(2)=3$. Similarly, $f(3)=13$.

This can clearly be done with recursion using dynamic programming. The number of orderings is equivalent to the number of difference equivalence classes for subsets of the element set. I was not able to think of a good recursive solution, and found the following one:

$f(n)=1+\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}(\binom{n}{i}f(n-i))$

It seems to work for the small numbers I could try on. Can anyone point me to the intuition for how this answer was reached? Usually with dynamic programming one would write each set as the sum of two expressions: when the element is "taken" in the current step, and when it isn't (like in the knapsack problem). This logic appears to fail here, as the $1$ represents the one equivalence class where all elements are equivalent.

Comment: Are you aware that a direct answer is possible ? Were the elements all distinct, the number of possible orderings with a "$<$" symbol would be $n!$. There are $n-1$ signs "$<$". As each of them can be replaced by an equality sign, we have to count how many subsets among the $n-1$ "$<$" signs we can choose for replacing them with a "$=$" sign ; thus, to each of the $n!$ orderings we can associate $2^{n-1}$ possible ways for assigning equality signs. Thus the answer is $n! 2^{n-1}$.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I wasn't originally sure whether to post the question here because it's a computer science question, but it's grounded in mathematics. I saw that there were some similar questions here though. The thing is, factorials are computationally expensive and usually the complexity of problems like this is higher by the 'direct' method than dynamic programming. Having said that, the formula $n!2^{n-2}$ doesn't work, as it ignores equivalences like $a=b=c\equiv a=c=b$, $a=b<c\equiv b=a<c$ etc.

Comment: 1) I don't understand your argument about the expensive character of the computation of a factorial because in this direct method, it is computed only once for all. 2) I am not convinced (but maybe I am wrong) by the fact that my method ignores the equivalence you mention : I stick to the model of an array sorting of numbers with hopefuly multiple equalities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the OEIS sequence [A000670](http://oeis.org/A000670) (Fubini numbers or ordered Bell numbers) and much information about computing it and combinatorial interpretations is there.

Answer (score 1):

(This is a comment, not an answer.)

These appear to be
related to the
Bell numbers,
which count the number of partitions of a set
(see
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BellNumber.html
or
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number).

They satisfy the recurrence
$B_{n}
=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{n-1}{k}B_k
=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{n-1}{k}B_{n-1-k}
$.